# Convert from Portfolio post type to product post type

Tags: wordpress, themes

This is Wordpress code. Can someone help me to convert this portfolio grid items from from Portfolio post type to product post type?

This is the theme link http://demo.theme-fusion.com/.

The theme has a custom post type named avada_portfolio and this code is to list those posts in a grid portfolio. I want to convert it a portfolio of products in Woocommerce.

```
<?php
// Template Name: Portfolio Grid
get_header();
$content_css = 'width:100%';
$sidebar_css = 'display:none';
$sidebar_exists = false;
if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pyre_portfolio_full_width', true) == 'yes') {
    $content_css = 'width:100%';
    $sidebar_css = 'display:none';
    $sidebar_exists = false;
}
elseif(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pyre_portfolio_sidebar_position', true) == 'left') {
    $content_css = 'float:right;';
    $sidebar_css = 'float:left;';
    $sidebar_exists = true;
} elseif(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pyre_portfolio_sidebar_position', true) == 'right') {
    $content_css = 'float:left;';
    $sidebar_css = 'float:right;';
    $sidebar_exists = true;
} elseif(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pyre_portfolio_sidebar_position', true) == 'default') {
    if($smof_data['default_sidebar_pos'] == 'Left') {
        $content_css = 'float:right;';
        $sidebar_css = 'float:left;';
        $sidebar_exists = true;
    } elseif($smof_data['default_sidebar_pos'] == 'Right') {
        $content_css = 'float:left;';
        $sidebar_css = 'float:right;';
        $sidebar_exists = true;
    }
}

$class = '';

if($smof_data['grid_pagination_type'] == 'Infinite Scroll') {
    $class = 'portfolio-infinite';
}
if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pyre_portfolio_full_width', true) == 'no') {
    $class .= ' portfolio-grid-2';
}
?>
    <div id="content" class="portfolio portfolio-masonry <?php echo $class; ?>" style="<?php echo $content_css; ?>">
        <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <span class="entry-title" style="display: none;"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
            <span class="vcard" style="display: none;"><span class="fn"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span></span>
            <span class="updated" style="display:none;"><?php the_modified_time( 'c' ); ?></span>   
            <div class="post-content">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php $current_page_id = $post->ID; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php
        if(is_front_page()) {
            $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
        } else {
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        }
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'avada_portfolio',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'posts_per_page' => $smof_data['portfolio_items'],
        );
        $pcats = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'pyre_portfolio_category', true);
        if($pcats && $pcats[0] == 0) {
            unset($pcats[0]);
        }
        if($pcats){
            $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $pcats
            );
        }
        $gallery = new WP_Query($args);
        if(is_array($gallery->posts) && !empty($gallery->posts)) {
            foreach($gallery->posts as $gallery_post) {
                $post_taxs = wp_get_post_terms($gallery_post->ID, 'portfolio_category', array("fields" => "all"));
                if(is_array($post_taxs) && !empty($post_taxs)) {
                    foreach($post_taxs as $post_tax) {
                        if(is_array($pcats) && !empty($pcats) && (in_array($post_tax->term_id, $pcats) || in_array($post_tax->parent, $pcats )) )  {
                            $portfolio_taxs[urldecode($post_tax->slug)] = $post_tax->name;
                        }

                        if(empty($pcats) || !isset($pcats)) {
                            $portfolio_taxs[urldecode($post_tax->slug)] = $post_tax->name;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $all_terms = get_terms('portfolio_category');
        if( !empty( $all_terms ) && is_array( $all_terms ) ) {
            foreach( $all_terms as $term ) {
                if( array_key_exists ( urldecode($term->slug) , $portfolio_taxs ) ) {
                    $sorted_taxs[urldecode($term->slug)] = $term->name;
                }
            }
        }

        $portfolio_taxs = $sorted_taxs;

        if($smof_data['grid_pagination_type'] == 'Infinite Scroll') {
            $portfolio_category = get_terms('portfolio_category');
            $portfolio_taxs = array();

            if(empty($pcats) || !isset($pcats)) {
                foreach($portfolio_category as $portfolio_cat) {
                    $portfolio_taxs[urldecode($portfolio_cat->slug)] = $portfolio_cat->name;
                }
            } else {
                if( is_array($pcats) && !empty( $pcats ) ) {
                    foreach($pcats as $pcat) {
                        $term = get_term( $pcat, 'portfolio_category' );
                        $portfolio_taxs[urldecode($term->slug)] = $term->name;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(is_array($portfolio_taxs)) {
                asort($portfolio_taxs);
            }
        }

        if( ! post_password_required($post->ID) ):
        if(is_array($portfolio_taxs) && !empty($portfolio_taxs) && get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pyre_portfolio_filters', true) != 'no'):
        ?>
        <ul class="portfolio-tabs clearfix">
            <li class="active"><a data-filter="*" href="#"><?php echo __('All', 'Avada'); ?></a></li>
            <?php foreach($portfolio_taxs as $portfolio_tax_slug => $portfolio_tax_name): ?>
            <li><a data-filter=".<?php echo $portfolio_tax_slug; ?>" href="#"><?php echo $portfolio_tax_name; ?></a></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
            <?php
            while($gallery->have_posts()): $gallery->the_post();
                if($pcats) {
                    $permalink = tf_addUrlParameter(get_permalink(), 'portfolioID', $current_page_id);
                } else {
                    $permalink = get_permalink();
                }
                if(has_post_thumbnail() || get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pyre_video', true)):
            ?>
            <?php
            $item_classes = '';
            $item_cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'portfolio_category');
            if($item_cats):
            foreach($item_cats as $item_cat) {
                $item_classes .= urldecode($item_cat->slug) . ' ';
            }
            endif;
            $bgClass = '';
            ?>
            <div class="portfolio-item <?php echo $item_classes; ?> <?php echo $bgClass; ?>">
                <span class="vcard" style="display: none;"><span class="fn"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span></span>
                <span class="updated" style="display: none;"><?php the_time('c'); ?></span>
                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
                <div class="image" aria-haspopup="true">
                    <?php if($smof_data['image_rollover']): ?>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $permalink; ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php
                    if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pyre_image_rollover_icons', true) == 'link') {
                        $link_icon_css = 'display:inline-block;';
                        $zoom_icon_css = 'display:none;';
                    } elseif(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pyre_image_rollover_icons', true) == 'zoom') {
                        $link_icon_css = 'display:none;';
                        $zoom_icon_css = 'display:inline-block;';
                    } elseif(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pyre_image_rollover_icons', true) == 'no') {
                        $link_icon_css = 'display:none;';
                        $zoom_icon_css = 'display:none;';
                    } else {
                        $link_icon_css = 'display:inline-block;';
                        $zoom_icon_css = 'display:inline-block;';
                    }

                    $link_target = "";
                    $icon_url_check = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'pyre_link_icon_url', true); if(!empty($icon_url_check)) {
                        $icon_permalink = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pyre_link_icon_url', true);
                        if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'pyre_link_icon_target', true) == "yes") {
                            $link_target = ' target="_blank"';
                        }
                    } else {
                        $icon_permalink = $permalink;
                    }
                    ?>
                    <div class="image-extras">
                        <div class="image-extras-content">
                            <?php $full_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full'); ?>
                            <a style="<?php echo $link_icon_css; ?>" class="icon link-icon" href="<?php echo $icon_permalink; ?>"<?php echo $link_target; ?>>Permalink</a>
                            <?php
                            if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pyre_video_url', true)) {
                                $full_image[0] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pyre_video_url', true);
                            }
                            ?>
                            <a style="<?php echo $zoom_icon_css; ?>" class="icon gallery-icon" href="<?php echo $full_image[0]; ?>" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" title="<?php echo get_post_field('post_excerpt', get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>"><img style="display:none;" alt="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>" />Gallery</a>
                            <h3 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php echo $icon_permalink; ?>"<?php echo $link_target; ?>><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                            <h4><?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'portfolio_category', '', ', ', ''); ?></h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php elseif(!has_post_thumbnail() && get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pyre_video', true)): ?>
                <div class="image video full-video">
                    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pyre_video', true); ?>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php endif; endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        <?php themefusion_pagination($gallery->max_num_pages, $range = 2); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php if( $sidebar_exists == true ): ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <div id="sidebar" style="<?php echo $sidebar_css; ?>"><?php generated_dynamic_sidebar(); ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert post type of posts you can do it using custom query.

In your phpmyadmin execute this query

update wp_posts set post_type='products' where post_status='publish' and post_type='portfolio'

It will convert your post type.

Comment: Do you want to display portfolio like products? do you want to change only the display part??